# Creating an auto increment ID in bill

Tags: .net, vb.net

**i want to create an auto increment Fact id but the problem the fact id should be like this FA001
how to increment it every time when i save a fact**

Comment: What is supposed to look like when you get to FA999. What is the next id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use this methode

`string  bill ="fa"`

`string  Num = "001"`

`for i As integer = 0 to .Numcount -1`

`Num = val(Num)+1`

`if (Num.length >= 3 ) then`

`bill = bill & "Num"`

`else`

`Num= "0"  & Num` 
`end if`

`next`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim stringvalue as string = "FA"
Dim intvalue As Integer = 1
Dim format As String = "000"
Dim ID = stringvalue + intvalue.ToString(format)
```

Then you just increase it by 1 everytime you save it, not too hard.

You should research more for what you need.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this, I wouldn't store F0001 as a primary key.  I would use a standard integer auto inc field.

Then if it was only required for display purposes, I would create a read only property in my data object layer that built the "F0001" using string formatting tools.

If it was required in the DB, I would create a second candidate key column that contained it